# Bigbluebutton Development html5 client not starting

Tags: npm, meteor, bigbluebutton

I have followed official documentation to setup bigbluebutton development environment but html5 client not starting , throwing following error. tried with  different server but same error

```
     if (oldPresenter?.userId !== currentPresenterId) {
W20201227-04:07:46.391(0)? (STDERR)                      ^
W20201227-04:07:46.392(0)? (STDERR)
W20201227-04:07:46.392(0)? (STDERR) SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
W20201227-04:07:46.392(0)? (STDERR)     at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
W20201227-04:07:46.393(0)? (STDERR)     at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
W20201227-04:07:46.393(0)? (STDERR)     at /home/ubuntu/dev/bigbluebutton/bigbluebutton-html5/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:393:30
W20201227-04:07:46.393(0)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
W20201227-04:07:46.394(0)? (STDERR)     at /home/ubuntu/dev/bigbluebutton/bigbluebutton-html5/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:220:19
W20201227-04:07:46.394(0)? (STDERR)     at /home/ubuntu/dev/bigbluebutton/bigbluebutton-html5/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:471:5
W20201227-04:07:46.394(0)? (STDERR)     at Function.run (/home/ubuntu/dev/bigbluebutton/bigbluebutton-html5/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/profile.js:510:12)
W20201227-04:07:46.395(0)? (STDERR)     at /home/ubuntu/dev/bigbluebutton/bigbluebutton-html5/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:470:11
```

i didn't change any file.

nodejs version v8.17.0

Answer (score 0):

node 8 doesn't support the `x?.y` syntax. You'll need to use the old-school:

```
     if (oldPresenter && oldPresenter.userId !== currentPresenterId) {
```

or whatever your logic schould be.

Comment: I updated note to latest same error exist

Comment: I assume you meant "node" instead of "note", right? But even if so, does my answer not work for you? it should!

Comment: Yes I meant Node :), Unfortunatly not worked. But for someone else have the same problem with fresh installed bigbluebutton dev env, you should be checkout V2.2.x-release branch,  and the error disappears.